How to handle PipelineRuns and Tasks which are sensitive to concurrency in tekton
I'm trying to figure out how to enforce that PipelineRuns start and end in the order in which they were started.
The reason I want this is because our pipelines also handle versioning of our applications. They do so by utilizing conventional commits, producing a semver-based version, adding that version to source, adding a tag to git, and pushing to the repository.
This means the task that which does this is subject to possible concurrency issues. I'd like to avoid this by enforcing sequential builds, or possibly some other solution.
I distinctly remember reading something like this in the Tekton documentation, but their documentation is rather unwieldy so I've been not been able to find it after reading it the first time.
If anyone knows how to handle PipelineRuns/Tasks which are sensitive to concurrency I'd love to know.
